# Black Background for Alert-dialog when animation applied

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I ve set animation to alertdialog. but the dialoges background turns black.

My code...

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
```

slide_out_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

slide_up_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
</style>
<style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>
```

How can i resolve this issue.?

Comment: your theme is the problem

Comment: How can i solve it.?

Comment: can y ou show your customize alert dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create custom dialog here with particular dialog Layout and load that layout in your Alertdialog.eg:

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

Your layout background color depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

Please do with this,

```
 <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and in your activity,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(WordActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Test");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
```

here that test means your custom view....and the black background is going by using android:windowBackground as transparent.